# Named parameters for stored procedures in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Can I use named parameters for stored procedures in MySQL? I need to call stored procedures something like this:

```
CALL stored_procedure(@param1 = "foo1", @param2 = "foo2");
```

**The answer is**

```
CALL stored_procedure(@param1 := "foo1", @param2 := "foo2");
```

Thanks for Pentium10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible formally.

But there is a workaround that can help. Use this:

```
CALL prcInsertStuff ( 
@paramName1 := nameValue1 
, @paramValue1 := paramValue1 
);
```

Comment: Hi Pentium10, unfortunatelly it will not help me. I need really named parameters. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You can't do that. But you can pass a name and a variable as pair.

Comment: Ah! I see! This looks much better. Gimme few seconds for the test please :-)

Comment: I have to modify my stored procedure call to: CALL stored_procedure(@param1 := "foo1", @param2 := "foo2");

Comment: I've tried the above answer and it still puts the parameters in the order they are defined in the sp, regardless of what you call them.

Comment: @KthProg use session variables

Comment: I'm not getting the connection. This doesn't do anything except create user variables with those values, and then pass them in just as it normally would.

Comment: This is close enough for me! I don't care if its not exactly the same! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

MySQL stored procedures do not support named parameters in any order. The feature request has been made in the past, for example:

- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73991

As you discovered, the workaround to use expressions to set session variables has nothing to do with the order of parameters. In other words, you can do the following:

```
CALL stored_procedure(@param1 := "foo1", @param2 := "foo2");
```

But the values "foo1" and "foo2" are still the first and second parameters, respectively.

If you want more flexibility, I suggest you write your stored procedure to accept *no* parameters, but use session variables directly.

```
SET @param1 := "foo1", @param2 := "foo2";
CALL stored_procedure();
```

In your procedure, you must then reference the variables as `@param1`, `@param2`, etc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stored_procedure()
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col1 = @param1 AND col2 = @param2;
END
```

Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html